# Choosing the correct rule

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am having a tricky time with Google-Tag-Manager.

I have a form on a particular page that I'd like to track successful submissions off.

The URL where the form lives has two variations:

```
https://example.com/secure/billinginfo?prodCode=B
https://example.com/secure/billinginfo?prodCode=P
```

I have a Form Submit Listener tag that fires on all pages.

I've now created a new tag to use the form listener:

```
Universal Analytics;
Track Type: Event;
Firing Rules: {{event}} = gtm.formSubmit and {{url}} matches regex https://example.com/secure/billinginfo?prodCode+
```

So I just added a regex "+" for the last two characters of each variant of the URL, which ends in either "`=B`" or "`=P`". But the tag did not fire.

I also tried simply using `{{url}} contains /secure/billinginfo?prodCode` but that also did not work.

What would be the best way to set up a rule to fire the tag when either version of the URL is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your RegEx: You're not escaping the `?`.

```
secure/billinginfo\?prodCode=[B,P]
```

Also, try using `{{path}}` macro instead of `{{url}}` macro.

Comment: Thanks @Blexy I never considered escaping the ? I ended up using path that seemed to do the trick